# Sort a resource based on the number of associated resources of other type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Movie model that has many comments,
I simply want to sort them (Movies) using SQL Inside active record based on the number of associated comments per movie.

How can we achieve a behavior like this in the most efficient way.

I want to do this on the fly without a counter cache column

Comment: use counter cache column called comments_count that holds the number of comments of a movie, then order the movie by the comments_count column. `Movie.order_by('comments_count desc')`

Comment: @MahmoudSayed and what if I want to do it on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
@top_ten_movies = Comment.includes(:movie).group(:movie_id).count(:id).sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse.first(10)
```

- include(:movie) this to prevent n+1 in sql
- group(:movie_id) = grouping based on movie for each comment
- sort_by{|k,v|v} = this will result an array of array for example [[3,15],[0,10][2,7],...]
- for first part [3,15] = meaning movie with id = 3, has 15 comments
- you can access array @top_ten_movies[0] = first movie which has top comments
- default is ascending, with reverse you will get descending comments